# Is it possible to track what pages (or domains) a banner ad appears on?

Tags: flash, tracking, ads, adsense

I am building a flash banner ad which I will traffic among some major ad networks.  Is it possible for me to track what sites (or domains) my ad has appears on, without relying on their reporting?

Keep in mind that these banner ads are served inside iframes on the sites.

Thanks!

Comment: Are you going through Eyeblaster (MediaMind) or DoubleClick (Google)? Also shouldn't you or the client have a schedule outlining where they're going to appear anyway, considering you have to pay for slots..

Answer (score 1):

one possible way is to make a request to a domain you do have reporting on and track that reqest. For example add 1x1 png on a domain that you can track all requests, call that tiny image from within the banner. Record, capture, profit!!!

Generally though the ad-networks prohibit you from making any outside calls, so depends on your specific restrictions, as well as how you want to track.

Comment: But what if the ad is served within an iframe - how can the 1x1 pixel know the URL of the parent site?

Answer (score 1):

not sure if this will help you, but you can try using [Google Analytics Tracking for Adobe Flash](http://code.google.com/apis/analytics/docs/tracking/flashTrackingIntro.html):

> The Google Analytics Tracking for Adobe Flash component makes it easy
>   for you to implement Google Analytics in your Flash-driven content.
>   This component, developed by Adobe Systems, Inc., contains all of the
>   functionality of the Google Analytics Javascript code. The Flash
>   Tracking component is a compiled tracking object native to
>   ActionScript 3, making Analytics implementation intuitive in Flash,
>   and Flex development environments.